# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in Electron Js when using require() in html page

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm new to Electron Js and I am trying to make a custom titlebar as a project. I made the titlebar in a html page called `nav.html` and imported it in `index.html` **(the main page)**

**nav.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />


    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      button {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        height: 35px;
      }
      .header {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
#title {
        width: 80%;
        -webkit-app-region: drag;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }
      svg.restore {
        fill: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        padding: 10px 14px;
      }
      svg.restore:hover {
        fill: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
        background-color: #5e5e5e !important;
      }

      button.minimize {
        padding: 3.5px 16px;
        color: white;
      }
      button.minimize:hover {
        background-color: #5e5e5e !important;
      }

      .maximize {
        cursor: default;
        fill: white;
        padding: 10px 14px;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        display: none;
      }
      .maximize:hover {
        background-color: #5e5e5e !important;
        color: white;
      }

      button.close {
        padding: 3.3px 14px;
        color: white;
      }
      button.close:hover {
        background-color: red !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div
      class="header"
      style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;"
    >
      <div id="title"></div>
      <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
        <button
          style="font-size: 25px; cursor: default"
          class="minimize"
          id="minimize"
        >
          -
        </button>
        <button>
          <svg
            width="25px"
            height="25px"
            viewBox="0 0 512 512"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            style="cursor: default"
            class="restore"
            id="restore"
          >
            <path
              d="M352,153H40.247a24.028,24.028,0,0,0-24,24V458a24.028,24.028,0,0,0,24,24H352a24.028,24.028,0,0,0,24-24V177A24.028,24.028,0,0,0,352,153Zm-8,32v45.22H48.247V185ZM48.247,450V262.22H344V450Z"
              class="ci-primary"
            />
            <path
              d="M472,32H152a24.028,24.028,0,0,0-24,24v65h32V64H464V339.143H408v32h64a24.028,24.028,0,0,0,24-24V56A24.028,24.028,0,0,0,472,32Z"
              class="ci-primary"
            />
          </svg>

          <svg
            viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
            version="1.1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            class="maximize"
            id="maximize"
          >
            <path
              d="M896 85.333333H128a42.666667 42.666667 0 0 0-42.666667 42.666667v768a42.666667 42.666667 0 0 0 42.666667 42.666667h768a42.666667 42.666667 0 0 0 42.666667-42.666667V128a42.666667 42.666667 0 0 0-42.666667-42.666667z m-42.666667 768H170.666667V426.666667h682.666666z m0-512H170.666667V170.666667h682.666666z"
            />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <button
          style="font-size: 25px; cursor: default"
          class="close"
          id="close"
        >
          &times;
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = document.title;
      // ipc connection between main.js and nav.html buttons to mainpulate the function of the window asynchronously
      const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
      const ipc = ipcRenderer;

      const restore = document.querySelector("#restore");
      const maximize = document.querySelector("#maximize");
      const minimize = document.querySelector("#minimize");
      const closeBtn = document.querySelector("#close");

      // close the window
      closeBtn.onclick = function(){
        ipc.send("closeApp");
        console.log('mama earth');
      }
      restore.onclick = function () {
        maximize.style.display = "block";
        restore.style.display = "none";
      };
      maximize.onclick = function () {
        restore.style.display = "block";
        maximize.style.display = "none";
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have added inline styles as well as style tag and script tag in the same html document

Problem comes when I am not able to use `require('electron')` in a script tag. I am trying to make the top window buttons and using the `ipcRenderer` to process them to main.js.

**Main.js :**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow , ipcMain} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const ipc = ipcMain

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 700,
    center: true,
    minHeight: 700,
    minWidth: 1200,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation : true,
      devTools: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')

  //close window function 
  ipc.on('closeApp', () => {
    console.log('app is closed')
    win.close()
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

I have just added the index.html and preload.js for no confussion :

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    
    <title>Home</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="nav-placeholder" src="nav.html" width="100%" style="border: none;height: 35px !important;" loading="eager"></iframe>
    <a href="nav.html">Go to nav page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Preload.js :**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(selector)
      if (element) element.innerText = text
    }
  
    for (const type of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
      replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type])
    }
  })
```

I tried using require JS but I had no idea how to do it. If anyone has an answer to it or can guide me through the error it would be highly appreciatable!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting `webPreferences.contextIsolation` in `createWindow` to false? (If it works, it surely is not the best solution because Context Isolation is actually an important security feature)

Comment: I was following a tutorial @ZerobyteHD and in that he said just to do it so that it works but it did'nt. My problem is that I am not able to use `const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");` and it is giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

You probably read some deprecated articles or forum posts, because calling electron from an HTML file is now an "old way" to use the ipcRenderer.

For security reasons, `electron` should not be directly accessible from your HTML page. You should only require `ipcRenderer` from your preload script, where you can put it in a method. Then, you can access your method by sharing it with the [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge).

I know this might be confusing at the beginning. You can find a well documented example here about What/How to use the ContextBridge
https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md

Comment: Yeah Nice Info , I went through it and tried to change some code but it started it giving me some more weird error. Can you give me a structured idea of how do I write my code?

Comment: Thanks for the mention @Dony!

Answer (score 0):

@Dony is right, in today's Electron world, using `require` in the HTML page is a big *no no*. (disclaimer, *I* wrote the blog post that he's linking to).

I'm curious reading your question, are you looking to create a *navigation* or a *menu*? If it's a menu, then Electron has support to do this natively through the [Menu](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu/) class.

You ask a really great question, because setting this up in a secure way requires some communication between the renderer and main processes. [My template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template) uses this pattern within the menu to update the app's language, alongside [this package](https://github.com/reZach/i18next-electron-fs-backend).

I unfortunately don't have enough time to thoroughly go into detail at this moment, but will suggest you first take a peak at whether it may be a *menu* you are looking to add your functionality to. If it is, I hope some of my repository's files can direct you in the place where you can see how to set up the link between the js and the html file within an Electron application.

I'm also currently in the process of writing an "Ultimate Electron guide" that would cover these topics in a thorough blog post. I estimate it's many weeks out as I intend to go in *great* detail to explain Electron concepts such as this one. It'll be up on https://www.debugandrelease.com/ when I post it (subscribe if you'd like an email when it goes out).